# Comprehensive JavaDoc-like documentation for Mozilla/Firefox extension developers?

Tags: documentation, firefox-addon, javadoc

Is there any thing like JavaDoc for Mozilla/Firefox that helps extension developers?

For example where can I find what `delayedOpenTab()` does and how to use it?

Comment: "What does this function do and how do I use it?" may not be the most useful question to ask. It might be better to approach it as, "I'm trying to do X. How do I accomplish that?" and then it may be that `delayedOpenTab` is the answer to your question.

Comment: @MatrixFrog - That's another question, but `What exactly x do and how exactly it should be used?` is still another valid, important, popular question. And that's why JavaDoc exist and is popular not only in Java community. I saw delayedOpenTab in sample code but before using it I needed to know more it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be [Mozilla Cross-Reference](http://mxr.mozilla.org/) and `delayedOpenTab()` is [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/ident?i=delayedOpenTab&tree=mozilla&filter=).

Comment: mxr is just source code. So if there are good comments in the source, then yes. Of course, that is often not the case, so mxr is not always as useful as you might hope.

Comment: MXR is source code + docs, docs are not as comprehensive as normal JavaDoc but still helpful. I hope I will find something better or someone else knows it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/addons) is the main resource for all things Mozilla. And [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) is a page about `delayedOpenTab()`.

Comment: MDN is neither like JavaDoc nor comprehensive and on that page `delayedOpenTab` is "only used" in a sample code about something else.

Comment: There are people working to make it more and more comprehensive all the time. If you can make it better/clearer, it's a wiki so you can improve it yourself. If not, you can talk to the people who are most closely involved with it, and make suggestions to them, for example by joining the #devmo channel on Mozilla's IRC server.

Comment: @MatrixFrog - I think "comprehensive" was a misleading  word I used, by comprehensive I mean "comprehensive like JavaDoc".